# How to fix csv upload with ID "3/Ewurafua/processed.cleveland.data.csv" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I am trying to upload a csv file on the django admin site using the tomwalker django-quiz-app open source library from github, when it tells me that the upload was successful but when i try to access the uploaded file, it gives an error.

```
 def csv_upload_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
  if not instance.completed:
    csv_file = instance.file
    decoded_file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
    reader = csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    header_ = next(reader)
    header_cols = convert_header(header_)
    print(header_cols, str(len(header_cols)))
    parsed_items = []

    '''
    if using a custom signal
    '''
    for line in reader:
        # print(line)
        parsed_row_data = {}
        i = 0
        print(line[0].split('\t'), len(line[0].split('\t')))
        row_item = line[0].split('\t')
        for item in row_item:
            key = header_cols[i]
            parsed_row_data[key] = item
            i+=1
        # create_user(parsed_row_data) # create user
        parsed_items.append(parsed_row_data)
        # messages.success(parsed_items)
        print(parsed_items)
    csv_uploaded.send(sender=instance, user=instance.user, csv_file_list=parsed_items)

    instance.completed = True
    instance.save()


   post_save.connect(csv_upload_post_save, sender=CSVUpload)
```

I expected to be able to view the file since it showed that the upload was successful but it prints out
      "Csv upload with ID "3/Ewurafua/processed.cleveland.data.csv" doesn't 
      exist. Perhaps it was deleted?".